# Python Twisted: How to make the reactor poll a Pipe along with internet sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, pipe, python-multiprocessing, twisted

I would like to use Twisted as a client/server manager that is part of regular Python objects.
The solution I am trying to implement is to isolate Twisted in its own process using `multiprocessing.Process`, and communicate with this process through `multiprocessing.Pipe`.

I have coded the client/server logic with Twisted already, but now I am stuck at interfacing the `multiprocessing.Pipe` communication with the reactor.

I am a beginner with Twisted so I may be missing something obvious, but from what I understand about how reactors work, I guess the reactor is somehow supposed to poll from my `multiprocessing.Pipe` along with the sockets that it already seems to handle nicely. So my question is, how can I make the reactor listen to my `multiprocessing.Pipe` on top of what it is already doing please?

Thus far my code looks something like this:

```py
class ServerProtocol(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, server):
        self._server = server

    def connectionMade(self):
        pass

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        pass

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        pass


class ServerProtocolFactory(Factory):

    protocol = ServerProtocol

    def __init__(self, server):
        self.server = server

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return ServerProtocol(self.server)


class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self, pipe):
        """
        This is called in its own process
        """
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, self._port)
        endpoint.listen(ServerProtocolFactory(self))
        reactor.run()  # main Twisted reactor loop


class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self._pipe = Pipe()
        self._server = Server()
        self._p = Process(target=self._server.run, args=(self._pipe, ))
        self._p.start()

    def stop(self):
        # I want to send some stop command through the Pipe here
        self._p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = MyObject()
    # do stuff here
    obj.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Twisted will work as run this way (i.e., as the target of a `multiprocessing.Process`).  Let's assume it will, though.

`multiprocessing.Pipe` [is documented as](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) returning a two-tuple of `multiprocessing.Connection` objects.  `multiprocessing.Connection` is documented as having a `fileno` method returning a file descriptor (*or handle*) used by the `Connection`.

If it is a file descriptor then there is probably a very easy path to integrating it with a Twisted reactor.  Most Twisted reactors implement [`IReactorFDSet`](https://twisted.org/documents/21.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorFDSet.html) which has an `addReader` method which accepts an [`IReadDescriptor`](https://twisted.org/documents/21.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReadDescriptor.html) value.

`Connection` is not quite an `IReadDescriptor` but it is easily adapted to be one:

```py
from attrs import define
from multiprocessing import Connection
from twisted.python.failure import Failure

@define
class ConnectionToDescriptor:
    _conn: Connection

    def fileno(self) -> int:
        return self._conn.fileno()

    def doRead(self) -> None:
        some_data = self._conn.recv()
        # Process some_data how you like

    def connectionLost(self, reason: Failure) -> None:
        self._conn.close()
```

If you wrap this around your read `Connection` and then pass the result to `reactor.addReader` the reactor will use `fileno` to figure out what to monitor for readiness and call `doRead` when there is something to read.

You could apply similar treatment to the write end of the pipe if you also want reactor-friendly support for sending bytes back to the parent process.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I have just realized that pipes have limited buffer sizes and that I should probably use local sockets instead for my application though.

Comment: Sockets also have limited buffer sizes (though pipes might be limited to smaller buffers, I forget).  So do all kinds of file descriptors, as far as I know.  So you have to write code to deal with the case where the buffer is full regardless.